# Python packages: contents import each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a Python package and the files inside need to import each other.

#### File structure (interactive):

```html
<script>var n='appendChild';var m='createTextNode';var l='setAttribute';var k='createElement';var j=document;var a=j[k]('pre');var b=j[k]('div');b[l]('style',`border-right:1px solid #000;width:100px;position:absolute;`);var c={'main.py':'import package<br><br>print(package.Multiply(3, 4))','/package':'','  __init__.py':'from add import Add<br>from multiply import Multiply','  add.py':'def Add(n1, n2):<br>  return n1 + n2','  multiply.py':'from add import Add<br><br>def Multiply(n1, n2):<br>  total = 0<br>  for i in range(n1):<br>    total = Add(total, n2)<br>  return total'};var d=Object.keys(c);for (let i=0;i<d.length;i++){let e=d[i];let f=c[e];let g=j[k]('a');let h=j[m](e);g[n](h);g[l]('href','#');g[l]('onclick','i.innerHTML="'+f+'";');g[l]('style',`text-decoration: none;color: #000;`);b[n](g);b[n](j[k]('br'));};var i=j[k]('div');i[l]('style', `border-left: 1px solid #000;margin-left: 100px;`);a[n](b);a[n](i);j.body[n](a);</script>
```

#### What currently happens:

When I run `main.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'add'` from line 1 of `__init__.py`.

If I change it to:

```html
<script>var n='appendChild';var m='createTextNode';var l='setAttribute';var k='createElement';var j=document;var a=j[k]('pre');var b=j[k]('div');b[l]('style',`border-right:1px solid #000;width:100px;position:absolute;`);var c={'main.py':'import package<br><br>print(package.Multiply(3, 4))','/package':'','  __init__.py':'from <span style=\"background-color:#afa;\">package.</span>add import Add<br>from <span style=\"background-color:#afa;\">package.</span>multiply import Multiply','  add.py':'def Add(n1, n2):<br>  return n1 + n2','  multiply.py':'from <span style=\"background-color:#afa;\">package.</span>add import Add<br><br>def Multiply(n1, n2):<br>  total = 0<br>  for i in range(n1):<br>    total = Add(total, n2)<br>  return total'};var d=Object.keys(c);for (let i=0;i<d.length;i++){let e=d[i];let f=c[e];let g=j[k]('a');let h=j[m](e);g[n](h);g[l]('href','#');g[l]('onclick',`i.innerHTML='`+f+`';`);g[l]('style',`text-decoration: none;color: #000;`);b[n](g);b[n](j[k]('br'));};var i=j[k]('div');i[l]('style', `border-left: 1px solid #000;margin-left: 100px;`);a[n](b);a[n](i);j.body[n](a);</script>
```

then it works. It seems as if I have to change all of the import directories, to fit the directory of the main file? If it is, is there some variable associated with this too?

#### My questions are:

1. How can I re-write `__init__.py` so that `main.py` performs correctly
2. How can I re-write `multiply.py` so that it can import `add.py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FabianP said, I had to change `from __ import __` to `from .__ import __`. Here is the new file structure showing the fix:

```html
<script>var n='appendChild';var m='createTextNode';var l='setAttribute';var k='createElement';var j=document;var a=j[k]('pre');var b=j[k]('div');b[l]('style',`border-right:1px solid #000;width:100px;position:absolute;`);var c={'main.py':'import package<br><br>print(package.Multiply(3, 4))','/package':'','  __init__.py':'from <span style=\"background-color:#afa;\">.</span>add import Add<br>from <span style=\"background-color:#afa;\">.</span>multiply import Multiply','  add.py':'def Add(n1, n2):<br>  return n1 + n2','  multiply.py':'from <span style=\"background-color:#afa;\">.</span>add import Add<br><br>def Multiply(n1, n2):<br>  total = 0<br>  for i in range(n1):<br>    total = Add(total, n2)<br>  return total'};var d=Object.keys(c);for (let i=0;i<d.length;i++){let e=d[i];let f=c[e];let g=j[k]('a');let h=j[m](e);g[n](h);g[l]('href','#');g[l]('onclick',`i.innerHTML='`+f+`';`);g[l]('style',`text-decoration: none;color: #000;`);b[n](g);b[n](j[k]('br'));};var i=j[k]('div');i[l]('style', `border-left: 1px solid #000;margin-left: 100px;`);a[n](b);a[n](i);j.body[n](a);</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the current directory before importing.

In `__init__.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "yourpath/package")
from add import Add
from multiply import Multiply
```

After that in `multiply.py` you can just import `add` module:

```py
from add import Add
```

Comment: Do not miss with PYTHONPATH, do it right and use relative import...  In `multiply.py`, use `from .add import Add`

Comment: Is there any documentation for this @FabienP ? If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @DanW-B Plenty, starting with [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision), then there's a lot of articles explaining python relative import, you can ask google or have a look at [this one](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) which is fairly complete, or [this other](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).